# Severe issue. Email alerts failed and no email notifications were send

Tags: process-builder, email-alert, issue

I'm having a serious issue on my production environment.

I have an automation process configured by the process builder which updates the status field of the Account object and triggers an email alert hence notifying the user that the status of the record was altered.

For some reason today the automation process suddenly stopped generating email alerts hence failed to send notifications to the users.

I've checked the test diliverability but I received all 48 emails generated by Salesforce.

Is there some limit in terms of generating email alerts and sending notification emails in Salesforce?

Please advise how to be able to track all failed emails and why all of a sudden the generating of emails failed?

Comment: Does the status field of the accounts which you expected and email for get updated?

Comment: You may want to check to see if your org was exceeding email limits during the period. You could possibly add the limit check to your process (easy to do in Apex, not so easy in PB) before sending the email(s). If no emails available, then in Apex, you'd write to a debug log or error handler. Not certain what options you'd have that are equivalent in PB unless you called an invocable to write to a debug log to tell yourself you didn't have email limits available.

Comment: did you look in email logs to see if emails were sent?

Comment: You can check `email logs` where it will generate logs of email sent from sf side and it list all things there. Like receipient, status of mail, timing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a limit on email see [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_email_workflow.htm&language=en_US&type=0)